# Splunk get combined result from 2 events

Tags: join, transactions, splunk

I am splunk noob trying to write a query for a couple of hours but not successful so far.
I want to count the number of times the command 'install' was triggered and the exit code was '0'
Each install command writes log in a new file with format 'install_timestamp' so I am searching for source="install*"

Using 2 source files as example

```
source1:
event1:command=install
... //a couple of other events
event100:exit_code=0

source2:
event1:command=install -f
... //a couple of other events
event100:exit_code=0
```

In this case I want the result to be 1. Only 1 occurrence of exit_code=0 when command was 'install' (not -f)
The thing that's confusing me is that the information for command and exit_code is in different events, I can get each of the two events separately but able to figure out how to get the combined result.

Any tips on how can I achieve the result I want ? - Thanks!

Comment: Transactions are one approach that might help, check out the docs  http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/transaction

Answer (score 0):

It's a little crude but you could do something like this...

("One String" NOT "Bad String") OR "Another String" | stats count by source | where count > 1

It will basically give you a list of files that contain events matching both strings. For your example this would be something like...

("command=install" NOT "-f") OR "exit_code=0" | stats count by source | where count > 1